# A good dictionary/corpus to crosscheck plural nouns

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am using "nltk" to identify nouns and then "inflect" to find the plural form of the noun. I have added a contingency where the plural form is crosschecked with a dictionary/corpus and if that plural word is not present then append "(s)" rather than using the plural form. The following is a small part of the code (the crosschecking part).

```
import inflect    
word = input()
p = inflect.engine()
pluralized = p.plural(word
with open("words.rtf") as f:
  text = f.read().strip().split()
  if pluralized in text:
     newword = pluralized
  else:
     newword = word+"(s)"
print(word," : ",newword)
```

The problem is that the dictionary/corpus I am using, "words.rtf" doesn't have most of the plural forms of possible words. Is there a text file with more plural examples or a better way to crosscheck. I want to reject plurals of abbreviations and acronyms, and accept only plurals of proper English words.
For example,

```
knife: knives
ID: ID(s) #not IDS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something to help with inflections you can checkout [pyInflect](https://github.com/bjascob/pyInflect) or [LemmInflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect).  These will do a much better job for you than NLTK.

If you're really just looking for a list of words, check out the Debian package [wamerican](https://packages.debian.org/stable/text/wamerican).  If you're on Linux it's probably already installed in `/usr/share/dict`.  For windows, I believe you can use 7-zip or several other programs to extract the .deb file, then just use the word list inside the archive.

There are also larger list like wamerican-large, -huge and -insane and wbritish versions (see similar packages on the right side of the wamerican page).